# relationship between correlation, covariiance and conditional distribution

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, covariance, covariance-matrix

What are the relationships between correlation and conditional distribution. For instance, given three dependent variables, `X1, X2` and `X3`. If their respective correlation matrix is known, are there ways to get the conditional distribution, such as `P(X1|X2)` or `P(X1|X2,X3)`?

Answer (score 2):

No. The correlation is a summary statistic, while (conditional, joint) distributions involve the complete information about how the three random variables are related. But, you can generate the correlation matrix from the *joint* distribution. Your query is only possible in very speciaş cases, e.g. when variables are jointly normal, with known means and variances.